# selenium_Login to gmail_Getting Error Exception in thread "main"

Tags: selenium

I am writing selenium program to Login to Gmail account.I have given username through source code and further step is click Next button.

```
package com.core.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Gmaildemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\REKHA\\SOFTWARES\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("rekha.sompalli@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("RveJvd snByac")).click();
    }

}
```

Getting below error.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Getting below error.It is not able to recongnise **Next** button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to click the `<span>` element, which is wrong. The `span` doesn't have the click functionality. aim for the `div` element with id `identifierNext`. try this: `driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();`

Selenium doesn't allow compund class names in `By.className`. Even if it did, that particular name, `"RveJvd snByac"`, is not unique on the webpage and may yield different result than expected.